# Можно ли по указателю на функцию определить местонахождение кода функции?

Tags: c++, c

Есть указатель на некоторую функцию. Можно ли по этому указателю понять, где находится эта функция: является ли она частью исполняемого файла или же функция находится в динамической библиотеке?

Может быть адреса функций из динамических библиотек как-то отличаются от адресов функций из исполняемого файла, или ОС предоставляет какой-нибудь специфичный API для определения местонахождения функций?

Вопрос в общем-то сугубо теоретический, но если определить местонахождение возможно, то для чего это может использоваться на практике?

Comment: Можно, см. [man proc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Comment: динамическая библиотека является исполняемым файлом.

Comment: @user7860670, я имею ввиду, что есть, например, обычный `exe` файл, который мы решили запустить, он начал свою работу, и подгружает какие-то `dll`. Можно ли по указателю понять, находится ли функция в исходном `exe`-файле или в подгруженной библиотеке?

Comment: Можно использовать `GetModuleHandleExW` c `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS` и по названию файла понять, .exe это или .dll.